# Issue with the checkbox that duplicate the check with bootstrap for Ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

when I click on a checkbox, for Monday for example, the checbox is validated, but all the other Monday, for each element are validated.

I'll show you the template, that can be more clear for you.

[image: Example]

When I click on Monday, the check is validated for both, and the value inside the js is validated for both.

Here is the Handlebars.js templates that define the page. This file is **shedule-timeframe.hbs**.

```js
{{#if timeframe}}
    {{log "monday " timeframe.enabledOnMonday}}
    {{log "start " timeframe.startTime}}
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!--Be careful, it's monday, friday, tuesday, saturday, wednesday, sunday, thursday -->
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.monday')
                           property="enabledOnMonday" value=timeframe.enabledOnMonday}}
            {{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.friday')
                           property="enabledOnFriday" value=timeframe.enabledOnFriday}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.tuesday')
                           property="enabledOnTuesday" value=timeframe.enabledOnTuesday}}
            {{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.saturday')
                           property="enabledOnSaturday" value=timeframe.enabledOnSaturday}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.wednesday')
                           property="enabledOnWednesday" value=timeframe.enabledOnWednesday}}
            {{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.sunday')
                           property="enabledOnSunday" value=timeframe.enabledOnSunday}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.thursday')
                           property="enabledOnThursday" value=timeframe.enabledOnThursday}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        {{#form.element label=(t 'schedule.start_time')}}
            {{input type='text' placeholder='13:37'value=(mut timeframe.startTime) class='form-control'}}
        {{/form.element}}

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        {{#form.element label=(t 'schedule.end_time')}}
            {{input type='text' placeholder='18:42'value=(mut timeframe.endTime) class='form-control'}}
        {{/form.element}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

And here, this where I call this templates. This file is **shedule-form.js**. You can see that I call the file **schedule-timeframe.hbs** at the line 20.

```js
{{#bs-form formLayout="horizontal" model=schedule as |form|}}
 
    <legend>{{t 'timeframes'}}</legend>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                {{bs-button defaultText=(t 'add') type='success' onClick=(action                'addTimeframe')}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                {{bs-button defaultText=(t 'submit') type="primary" onClick=action      buttonType="submit"}}
            </div>
        </div>
         <br> <br>
        <div class="row">
            {{#each schedule.timeframes as |tf|}}
                {{log "tf " tf}}
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        {{schedule-timeframe form=form timeframe=tf model=tf}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        {{bs-button defaultText=(t 'remove_selected') type='danger'
                                    onClick=(action 'removeTimeframe')}}
                    </div>
                    <br> <br>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
{{/bs-form}}
```

tldr: I have an issue with the checbox that duplicate when I click on one of them, for same value, but on different **[timeframe]**.

Comment: Problem lies where are you defining `schedule.timeframes`? include that code  and initialization of this property `schedule.timeframes`

Comment: This is defined at the line 15:  {{#each schedule.timeframes as |tf|}} . When I do that, it catch all the **timeframes** inside **schedule**. For example, here, I have 2 objects, each timeframe with an ID of respectively 0 and 1. But maybe I didn't understand correctly what you are trying to explain to me!

Comment: Where are you putting value to `schedule.timeframes` and `schedule` - Route/controller code

Comment: Schedule is in the **model/schedule.js**, it has a link to **timeframes**, which is located in **components/schedule-timeframes.js**.

Comment: So in your route model hook you are having `this.stroe.findAll('schdedule')`. if possible include route model hook and model/schedule.js file code

Comment: What we need to verify is content inside `schedule.timeframes` are they referring the same instance only then this issue will come.

Comment: I'll make some test on my own thank you for the tips, I'll update it when I'll find something relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solve it by creating my own onChange!

```js
{{form.element controlType='checkbox' label=(t 'schedule.monday')
                           value=(mut timeframe.enabledOnMonday)
                           onChange=(action (mut timeframe.enabledOnMonday))}}
```

With this onChange, I can set the value of each timeframe.